# Postback event on text changed event

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I want to postback on every keypress/textchanged event in textbox but my javascript is not running. Am i missing something...????

My Html textbox is this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="Txt_Search" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" 
  onkeypress="Postback();" OnTextChanged="Txt_Search_TextChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
</asp:TextBox>
```

My Javascript code is this:

```
    function Postback() {
    __doPostBack('<%= Txt_Search.ClientID %>', '');
};
```

My on textchanged event is this:

```
 protected void Txt_Search_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderStructure.Nodes.Clear();
        Searchtxt();
    }
```

Comment: Have you used Page.IsPostback method?

Comment: @rootturk On textchanged event occurs when focus is removed from the textbox. I want to postback on every keyword entered. How will Page.ispostback help me...?????

Comment: I don't it is a good idea to postback for every key press in ASP.NET Web Forms, unless you are doing something with AJAX.

Comment: Hmm. I get it your problem. Why don't you use AJAX GET or POST method?  Do you want to  search as dinamitly?

Comment: I don't have that much knowledge of Ajax. I am making a search box and i have to postback on every character entered. If you can give me an example of search box using Ajax then that would be a great help but i'm wondering why my code is not running.

Comment: @rootturk Yes i want to search dynamically but don't have that much knowledge about Ajax. Does my code have any errors...????

Comment: i provide you a example of dynamic search box, just edit your question and add some more tags like jquery, and ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create sample projects ASP.NET WebForms and AJAX.

I Suggest you can use AJAX process .NET Generic Handler File. Please you research about [Generic Handler](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx) file.

Before create Generic Handler file "Search.ashx" and Paste above the code.

```
            public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

        var search = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["term"];

        //Dummy Data
        List<string> searchList = new List<string> { "Red", "Orange", "Ping", "Blue", "White", "Black" };

        string result = string.Empty;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
        {
            searchList = searchList.Where(x => x.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())).ToList();

            if (searchList != null && searchList.Count() > 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in searchList)
                {

                    result += "<li>" + item + "</li>";

                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result="<li> Not Found </li>";
        }
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write(result);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and Create Your Search Page, YourFile.aspx, my file name Search.aspx.

ASPX Page Code :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication7.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="txtSearch" class="js-search" value="Search" />

        <div class="searchResult">
            <ul>


            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
    </form>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>

        $(function () {
            $(".js-search").on('keyup', function () {

                var term = $('.js-search').val();
                if (term.length > 2) {
                    sendSearchRequest({ "term": term });
                }
            });

            function sendSearchRequest(value) {

                var datas = $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/Search.ashx',
                    cache: false,
                    async: false,
                    data: value,
                    success: function (term) {
                        $('.searchResult').empty();
                        $('.searchResult').append(term);
                    }

                });

            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This example when all three letters entered send ajax request search.ashx file and  contains search term and get result on search page.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Modify code as below and check

```
__doPostBack('Txt_Search', '');
```

Comment: No it's not running.

Answer (score 0):

here is demo for dynamic search in asp.net.

Your textbox should be:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="PopertyName" placeholder="Property Name" href="#"
                                propertyid="" runat="server" class="dropdownAnchor"
                                autocomplete="off" onkeydown="SearchProperty()"></asp:TextBox>
```

here we will call a function named searchProperty() onkeydown event.

so, your ajax should be,

```
function SearchProperty() {                            
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/Dashboard/NewDashboard.aspx/GetProperty") %>',
                            data: "{ 'prefix': '" + $("#PopertyName").val() + "'}",
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: "POST",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            success: function (data) {
                               //Your code to bind result that received from your back end.
                            },
                            error: function (response) {
                                alert(response.responseText);
                            },
                            failure: function (response) {
                                alert(response.responseText);
                            }
                        });
                    };
```

these function will call a GetPoprty() method on newDashboard.aspx.cs file.

so my back end method is,

```
[WebMethod]
public static List<Model.Property> GetProperty(string prefix)
{
   // Here you get your text in prefix 
 }
```